# Deleting entire table or moving all rows?

Tags: php, mysql

Couldn't find a better way to phrase this question.
Here's the deal:

I have a table with a fixed amount of rows (x), now I want to add 1 row to the top and remove the bottom one.
What's more efficient, deleting all table data after selecting it and rewriting it in the right order or move all entries accordingly?

Comment: `ORDER BY` seems like it would be more efficient...

Comment: SQL tables do not have a concept of FIRST and LAST rows. The implementation of a table is a bit more complicated then that. How do you define first and last row in your table?

Comment: Just add a new column `sort_order` of type `INT` (length 4 should be enough), place values in there and then `order by sort_order` in `DESC` or `ASC` order to meet Your desired result ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd thing to do however you can do it other way around. You can insert a row on a bottom and remove row from the top. Order by ID DESC and you get what you want.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE Where id = (SELECT min(id) FROM Table)
```